# Android studio gradle signature block verification error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android Studio 2.1.2.  After creating my first new project, it shows `Error:(1, 0) Cause: cannot verify signature block file META-INF/BCKEY`. I have attached image about this issue.

[image: screenshot]

I dont know what I do to fix this issue.  I am new to Android. Please help me to resolve this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.